# SSH Login Security - Proxy User with key and su to root

Tags: authentication, ssh

**Introduction:**

I know this question has been asked many times before in many different forms, but I wanted to come at this in a slightly different way.

I am considering many different ways to secure SSH login for this particular scenario, and I'd like to see how others would weigh in on the ideas outlined and potential benefits/drawbacks.

---

**The Environment:**

I'll be taking my use case as the example scenario here but its not completely unique.

- A network consisting of a dozen Linux servers providing data to both internal-only clients and internet-only clients through SMB/NFS/HTTPs
- A single administrator that performs all tasks within the network.
- A dedicated Linux administrator workstation not allowed to the internet and firewall'd off any inbound communication.
- Stored secrets for the network are on a Keepassxc database stored locally on the adminstration workstation. Database is protected with long passphrase only.
- Normal administration tasks solely include the troubleshooting/remediation of errors/issues as they occur, and the upgrading of software when needed (Security updates are automatic).

I'd like to tactle the idea of securing SSH access to these Linux servers within the scenario outlined above.

---

**Existing SSH Login Method:**

- SSH private keys (one per network 'domain', i.e. dmz, internal, wireless, ect.) are stored within keepass and only exposed on Keepass startup and added to the local workstation's sshagent.
- SSH key's give access to a standard user accross all servers (password authentication is disabled). This user is only given rbash as a login shell, and only has access to transfer files into their home directory and su to root.
- In order to perform said administration tasks, the admin must login to this unprivileged user with the key, and su to root using a password from the Keepass database.

---

**Brain Dump:**

*I apologize in advance for this wall of text.*

Now the reason I got to thinking about this subject is that I could not find any real technical reason why allowing login as root with a key poses any risk (password auth disabled). And I am questioning if the login method above has any real merits outside of the key authentication.

The SSH daemon already runs as root, and an unauthentication RCE of that process would theoretically result in root privileges (unless some sandbox such as selinux/apparmor is used and happen to mitigate the used vulnerability).

In this scenario, the key and root password are stored together inside the encrypted Keepass database. So theoretically the compromise of the administrator workstation would mean any combination of key and password is nullified by them being in the same place.

So prompted by this analysis, I would assume that no real security benefit is gained from having both key and password authentication. And that even an encrypted private key would be largely useless as the key is already stored encrypted in the Keepass database (although I am unsure if an encrypted private key stays encrypted when loaded into a sshagent).

The biggest gain in security that I can think of is adding something like a TOTP 2nd authentication factor from a secondary device. But extra software (like a TOTP plugin for PAM) could introduce additional vulnerabilities. Additionally, it might be negated if the workstation is compromised and an attacker could keylog the TOTP and establish their own communication channel while I was connected normally.

---

**Granting Privileges to non-root users:**

I have read some other posts about using a non-root user that has been granted specific permissions to perform most commands one would normally use with root. I would like to push back on that a little.

For one example, if I was going into a server to fix some error encountered on its web application, then I will most likely need access to journal or log files, systemctl to restart any services, write access to configuration files, and maybe the package manager to add/remove software.

If I were to try and grant all these permissions (and potentially more dangerous ones like modprobe) to a user, that user would start to become just as valueable as the root account. Which then moves the conversation back to "Why not just login as root".

One thought I had is that perhaps people taking this approach were more imagining running commands/software that can be dangerous to the server itself. I agree with that line of thinking, but not when the things being run are only internal commands. But since most administrator actions consist of things that need root privileges, it would make more sense to sudo to an unprivileged user to run the more risky things (unauth RCE client-side exploit against wget/curl??).

And on the topic of sudo, I realize many people would consider it as less of login security and more of an audit trail (or fine grained control to allow users to execute few/handful root-level commands). I can't argue with that, but sudo still provides root access. A better approach in my opinion is auditd. At least it would continue to audit commands run as root without sudo. I would also say that sudo adds another layer of software that has these elevated privileges and is exposed to unprivileged users (a potential local exploit vector).

---

**Attack Vectors:**

On top of all this, the attack surface for SSH within a network is very small when its locked down to a single client machine. The only other clients that would have access is inline devices like switches, routers, firewalls, and hypervisors (spoofing the admin workstation). So all these security measures would be for the sole scenario of a compromised mid-point device since compromise of the administrator workstation is pratically game over.

I suppose the only other attack vector is partial compromise of the workstation where the attacker has regular user privileges and is unable to read memory from Keepass or SSH agent and is directly attacking a servers SSH daemon over the network.

Although the TOTP 2FA addition would effectively mitigate all but an unauth RCE from a mid-point device.

---

**Idea for New Login Method:**

- SSH keys are still stored in Keepass database and added to SSH Agent.
- SSH keys provide access to the root user on all servers
- Maybe: TOTP 2FA from additional device

---

**Question/Conclusion:**

I do realize that the conversation drastically changes when talking about a network with multiple administrators or systems where the normal user interaction is through SSH.

Although it may seem like I've already made up my mind, I still think this is a worthwhile discussion and productive ideas and solutions can come out of it that the rest of the community can benefit from.

I'd really like to see what other's ideas are and engage with you all about best/better solutions.